# Is it possible to use report an error in update property function?

Tags: python

My code does not work but I want to achieve it.

````
import bpy

def show_error(self,context):
    self.report({"ERROR"},message="This is an error")
    
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New_TEST"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene,'new_prop',expand=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.new_prop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=[
                                                            ("OP1","Option 1",""),
                                                            ("OP2","Option 2","")],
                                                            update=show_error
                                                            )
    
    

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.new_prop
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````